# Is READ COMMITED transactional isolation level implicity when using FOR UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, distributed-transactions

After scouring the internet for information about Transactional Isolation levels, I understood that Row Locking in MySQL can be achieved by using either `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` and also that, a row locking query must execute after starting the transaction. So I came across some example illustrating the implementation of READ COMMITTED isolation level for two sessions like this:

```
--session 1
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT FirstName FROM EmployeeInfo
WHERE EmpID = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'  

SELECT FirstName FROM EmployeeInfo
WHERE EmpID = 1;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

The code for session 2 is like so:

```
 --session 2
 UPDATE EmployeeInfo
 SET FirstName = 'Frank'
 WHERE EmpID = 1;
```

In the code sample for session1, the **transaction  Isolation level** and the **beginning** of a transaction are explicit. In a certain blog I read that

- UPDATE statements implicitly create READ locks on affected rows in a transaction.
  So does this means that I can safely omit `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;` from session 1 and still get the same results.In other words how true is the statement **UPDATE statements implicitly create READ locks on affected rows in a transaction.**